# Sticky div with right: 0 css

Tags: html, css, sass, menu, position

I am trying to position my div with class "menu" div inside my "nav". I want this to appear on the most right position within my Nav but to also keep my "menu" div sticky so that when I scroll up/down, it scrolls. This is fine when below a width of about 1020px of the viewport but anything above I cant seem to get it to work. Can someone help me please?

NOTE: I don't want my entire Navbar to move, only the div that reads "Div Should stay inside navbar with right: 0"

Code for HTML/CSS:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .navbar {
                margin: 0 auto;
                max-width: 976px;
                background: red;
                align-items: flex-start;
            }

            .logo {
                color: rgb(184, 8, 8);
                top: 3.8rem;
                grid-column: 1;
                font-size: 2rem;
                font-weight: bold;
                height: 3rem;
                background-color: black;
            }

            .menu {
                color: white;
                position: fixed;
                z-index: 4;
                right: 0;
                margin-right: 0;
                padding-bottom: 1rem;
                top: 2.8rem;
                background-color: black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar">
            <div class="logo">Logo</div>
            <div class="menu">
                Div Should stay inside navbar with right: 0
            </div>
        </nav>

      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
      <div>dummy</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: `position: fixed` element are positioned relative to the viewport with no relation to the parent's position. The only way to match their horizontal axis is with JavaScript. There is also `position: sticky` which can be relative to parent element on one axis while relative to viewport on another axis, but it does not go out of the parent's bounds.

Answer (score 2):

Is this the outcome you're looking for?

```css
.navbar {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 976px;
    background: red;
    align-items: flex-start;
    position:relative;
}

.logo {
    color: rgb(184, 8, 8);
    top: 3.8rem;
    grid-column: 1;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 3rem;
    background-color: black;
}

.menu {
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
    right: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="logo">Logo</div>
        <div class="menu">
            Div Should stay inside navbar with right: 0
        </div>
    </nav>

  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
  <div>dummy</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Mohammed can you please mark this solution correct if it helped?

Answer (score 1):

I do only move the div with right 0 should stay in navbar when you scroll on the top. I am guessing you only want to fix the top bar as div with the menu class. maybe it will help you in some ways.

```css
.navbar {
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* max-width: 976px; */
  /* width: 75%; */
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  color: rgb(184, 8, 8);
  top: 3.8rem;
  grid-column: 1;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 3rem;
  background-color: black;
}

.menu {
  color: white;
  margin-right: 0;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0%;
  margin-right: 0.7em;
}

main {
  padding-top: 5em;
}

/* added by editor to shorten HTML code */
main div {
  height: 750vh;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="logo">Logo</div>
  <div class="menu">Div Should stay inside navbar with right: 0</div>
</nav>
<main>
  <div>dummy</div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have *commented* two lines and changed the `background-color` to blue(not solution)
run and check below

```css
.navbar {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 976px;
  background: red;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.logo {
  color: rgb(184, 8, 8);
  top: 3.8rem;
  grid-column: 1;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 3rem;
  background-color: black;
}

.menu {
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 4;
  /*right: 0;*/
  margin-right: 0;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  /*top: 2.8rem;*/
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="logo">Logo</div>
  <div class="menu">
    Div Should stay inside navbar with right: 0
  </div>
</nav>

<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
```

- as you see the main problem is the division is not horizontally stacked/aligned,its vertical!

## The solution

- is to align div horizontaly ,with `flex` ,`row` and some `margin` stuffs

```css
.navbar {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 976px;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;/*horizontal*/
  background-color: black;/*fill empty space*/
}

.logo {
  color: rgb(184, 8, 8);
  top: 3.8rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 3rem;
  background-color: black;
}

.menu {
  color: white;
  z-index: 4;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;/*for alignment in right side*/
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="logo">Logo</div>
  <div class="menu">
    Div Should stay inside navbar with right: 0
  </div>
</nav>

<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
<div>dummy</div>
```

> I would like to inform you about the [css Flex Tool](https://angrytools.com/css-flex/) ,try the website for your future web development!

> P.S if you dont understand codes purpose You can understand the code lines by commenting the lines